# How to use countif/Sumif where Date given as column header In MySQL or Excel

Tags: mysql, r, excel

I have a table like this

[image: Input file as mobile numbers and their daily data usage in MB]

I want output as Dates in one column and count of mobile numbers on each date which has crossed 150 MB of usage along with the sum of their usage in the next column.

[image: Output]

SAMPLE INPUT:

mobile_no,1-Sep-17,2-Sep-17,3-Sep-17,4-Sep-17,5-Sep-17
33045,50,110,200,100,34
33046,23,123,30,480,230
33047,102,217,23,145,186
33048,165,201,230,230,149
33049,22,229,160,71,173

Comment: Here Dates are column header in the input file.

Comment: Could you check if the expected output you showed is based on the example input.  Based on your logic, I am not getting the same output for some Dates

Comment: Please provide [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

Comment: I have added the sample input in this.

Comment: Tx, but if I look into your example, For sep_2, there are only 3 values that are greater than 150.  So, it is not clear how you are getting 881

Comment: Yes, I have changed it akrun. Thanks for that

Comment: @Dau_uaD - Are you okay with solution in excel using formula.

Comment: Yes. Excel, MySQL or R. Anything will work for me.

Answer (score 4):

In `Cell H2` enter the following formula

```
=OFFSET($A$1,0,ROW()-1)
```

Then in `Cell I2` enter

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($B$1:$F$1=H2)*($B$2:$F$6>150))
```

Finally in `Cell J2` enter

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($B$1:$F$1=H2)*($B$2:$F$6>150)*($B$2:$F$6))
```

Drag/Copy down formulas as required. Change the range as per your data. See image for reference.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In `R`, we can `gather` it to 'long' format, then grouped by the 'Date' column, get the number of 'mobile_no' and also the sum of 'val'

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>%
    gather(Date, val, -mobile_no) %>%
    filter(val > 150) %>%
    group_by(Date) %>%
    summarise(Count = n(), Sum_of_Usage = sum(val))
# A tibble: 5 x 3
#      Date Count Sum_of_Usage
#      <chr> <int>        <dbl>
#1 1-Sep-17     1          165
#2 2-Sep-17     3          647
#3 3-Sep-17     3          590
#4 4-Sep-17     2          710
#5 5-Sep-17     3          589
```

Comment: It works fine. What if I want to group it in buckets like 0-50, 50-100,100-150 and 150+

Comment: @Dau_uaD  You can use `cut` to create the groups